# Elasticsearch: IndicesQuery in new Java API versions

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-api

I have two indices. One contains a nested object and the other one doesn't. When I try to execute a query on both of these indices, I get the following error:

```
IllegalStateException[[nested] failed to find nested object under path [nestedItems]]; ]
```

Basically the same error as described [in this question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/search-on-a-nested-field-on-multi-indexes-multi-document-types-throw-queryparsingexception/40269). There the answer suggest that I should use the `indices` query. I was able to find method `QueryBuilders.indicesQuery(...)` in the [Java API 5.0 docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-indices-query.html).

However, the `indices` query was deprecated in 5.0 stating:

> Deprecated in 5.0.0. Search on the _index field instead.

I couldn't find a way to use the `_index` field in current API (7.0). How can I use it from Java?

Comment: Can you show the query you're trying to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: turned out that `nested` query has attribute `ignore_unmapped` which should be set to true.